# Cron отрабытавает неправильно

Tags: python, postgresql, cron

Есть скрипт на python

```
def dump_database():
print("\U0001F4E6 Preparing database backup started")
dump_db_operation_status = os.WEXITSTATUS(os.system(
    f"pg_dump -h {DB_HOSTNAME} -U {DB_USER} {DB_NAME} > "+DB_FILENAME+"_"+get_now_datetime_str()+".sql"
))
```

без crone всё отрабатывает как нужно. Вот как в Cron выглядит задача.

```
*/1 * * * * /home/rt/envs/backup/bin/python /home/rt/bd_backup/backup.py
```

Т.е. скрипт запускается через интерпретатор который в виртуальной среде.
Ещё раз, если эту команду я запущу в терминале всё работает , даи Cron каждую минуту орабатывает этот скрипт, но проблема в том, что когда я запускаю через терминал, то файл name.sql создаётся и там дамп базы данных, а вот когда этот скрипт отрабатывает Cron, то name.sql тоже создаётся , но файл пустой.

Comment: для начала стоит узнать, что программа pg_dump пишет в свой stderr: замените `>` на `&>`

Comment: Заменил,  весь бекап базы вывалился мне в консоль

Comment: при запуске cron-ом? не верю.

Comment: Запускал в консоле, кроном когда запустил создался просто пустой файл name.sql

Answer (score 0):

Вписывал очередь cron через sudo crone -e, помогло указать запуск скрипта в crone -e, без "sudo"